# Is it possible to run python script from another machine without installing imported modules?

Tags: python, module, server, libraries

Hi I have a Python (version 3.6) script which I developed in my laptop. But I would need to run the script from another server. I have installed the same version of Python on the server but not the modules which are imported in my script. These modules are installed on my laptop though.

Is it possible to run the python script from the server without installing the imported modules in the server?

Thanks
Shanto

Comment: No. you should install the dependency packages.

Answer (score 0):

It's true, technically you *do need to install the dependency packages*. However, you could **install them programmatically**, by including a prelude in your code which checks for those packages and if they are not available uses pip to install them.

**Not recommended:**
You could use the `pip` module to install with something like

```python
try:
    import package1
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    import pip    
    pip.main(['install', pandas])
    import package1
```

However, that way is not recommended since (among other reasons) `pip` is not thread-safe (see [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program) for the complete rationale).

**Recommended way: `subprocess`**
The recommended way is using the `subprocess` (standard) module

```python
try:
    import package1
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    import subprocess
    import sys    
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'package1']) 
    import package1
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good idea. It will try to install the package using the system python being run by an unprivileged user which won't have access to the system site-packages directories. There's a bit of a setup stage for python packages often abbreviated to `python setup.py install` but the simplest way would be to put your package (say `shanto`) on `pypi` and then ask users to `pip install shanto` to get it.

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason you are not able to install the packages on your server? You can try using virtualenv or install the required packages in the same folder as your code and deploy the entire folder to the server:

```
pip install -t <dir>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use pynistaller or py2exe or any other package for converting python scripts to executable files. 
Once executable files(.exe) files are created you can run that file without installing python modules